# Get the first 2 values from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a custom meta box script with a Wordpress based site and I need to get the first 2 values contained within an array.

Currently the output is like this -  `101112131415` if each value is `10`,`11`, `12`, `13`, `14` and `15`

I'm currently using a simple `foreach` rule to display them individually on a page but now my client wants to preview the first 2 values on another page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use a loop and break out after the second iteration.

Comment: Do you want the first 2 values in individual variables, or in an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming: `$array = array(10,11,12,13,14,15);`

```
$first2 = array_slice($array,0,2); //$first2 == array(10,11);
```

Or if you don't want a re-declaration:

```
array_splice($array,2); //$array == array(10,11);
```

Refs:

[array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_slice)

[array_splice](https://www.php.net/array_splice)

Comment: The current array is more like `101112131415` as oppose to `10,11,12,13,14,15`. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @DeanElliott So one element is `101112131415` ?? i.e. `array(0 => 101112131415)`

Comment: It's an array of ID's of uploaded attachments 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15 (These are just examples). So initially my array is just `101112131415` until I do the `foreach` to separate each one into it's own value

Comment: @DeanElliott So I'm still confused. Are you starting with an array, with each ID as a value, or a string of "IDIDIDIDIDID"? Just try using my code snippets on whatever variable you use in your `foreach` (before the foreach) - if you use the first one, change it to `foreach($first2`. I'm pretty sure it'll work, give it a try and then let me know if you have issues

Comment: Your snippet worked perfectly! Thank you, and apologies for the poor description of my problem. I'm relatively new to PHP

Comment: @DeanElliott No worries - glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to do that:

```
$out = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$value1 = $your_array[0];
$value2 = $your_array[1];
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this method will only work if the keys of the array elements are numeric and haven't been manipulated at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 2);   // returns "a", "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$arr = array("10", "11", "12", "13", "14");
$result = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list($first, $second) = array(1,2,3,4);
var_dump($first);
var_dump($second);
```

Output:-

```
int 1
int 2
```

See [list()](http://php.net/list) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for doing this.

```
$array = array(10,11,12,13,14,15);

$client_require = array_slice($array,0,2);
```